# How do I fix a resized to bigger space Gparted partition to show my data?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize, fsck

OK so I recently got a hard drive and have been using it alot lately. I was trying to re-size it (with data on it) to take up the free space I had just made by deleting some partitions with a bunch of GB.
So as I did this G-parted gave me an input/output error when it was 6.37gb in on making a copy to be able to re-size the partition.
i tried to fix it by doing a check and repair but it just froze the program after a couple seconds and my hard drive stalled.
I was worried by now so I tried to look up an easy fix. 
Boy was i wrong.
Im going to give a list of what commands i used but i have no idea what happened after this because like an amateur that i am i walked away and i did something else while it was doing automatic processes (-y):

```
sudo fdisk -lu 

sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdb5
```

i kept saying yes to what it was asking it was asking questions that required a yes or no answer then i held the y key down for a while i got annoyed and then i shut the terminal down by hitting the x in the corner.
              ^
I repeated this process twice.
I then preceded to open up a new terminal and typed this

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -y /dev/sdb5
```

it did its thing and said something like mount blah blah at the end i cant remember.

I then mounted my hard drive and it said i had 3.14gb out of 160gb available

I originaly had 115gb on that partition and it was full (before the resize)
I exited the terminal and did the same process again and it still was the same.

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk 

sudo apt-get install photorec
```

i installed both of these programs but i did not use them.

i did this:

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdb5
```

then i checked which superblocks were available for backup stuff:

```
 sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdb5
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
10354688 inodes, 41388032 blocks
2069401 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=0
1264 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872
```

i then proceded to do this:

```
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb5
```

i did not get that far and exited the terminal again.
i opened an new terminal and typed:

```
sudo e2fsck -y -b 32768 /dev/sdb5
```

it automatically restored the sectors it thought should have been restored but i came up with even less gb than before:
1.15GB out of 160GB

I then tried to use G-parted again to check and fix. it checked and fixed only 1.5gb.
I closed G-parted and continued to:
kind of just had it with my hard drive being broken and I stated to do more crazy stuff without thinking or making a backup:

```
sudo e2fsck -y -b 98304 /dev/sdb5
```

it was even worse now now i had 
1.03GB out of 160GB

i then typed this

```
sudo e2fsck -y -b  11239424 /dev/sdb5
```

and now i haven’t touched my hard drive since.

So if anybody can help me that would be appreciated! I can try to explain more if you ask me too.

Comment: For future reference, don't close a terminal when it is doing something. And also please don't use crude words here.

Comment: What crude words are you reffering to?

Comment: the p word. i have removed it.

Comment: Oh that was my mistake i typed this fast because i was in a hurry for work i did not realize what i had typed.